# Controlling dropdown list box width

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to find a way to control the width of the items displayed in a **databound** drop down list box. I am currently trying to use jQuery to control the width of the options displayed, but am having problems coming up with the correct syntax. Any help would be appreciated or a better idea of some method to handle the problem. The DropDown is an ASP control so getting to the option part is the issue as shown below.

```
<script src="../../scripts/jquery-1.7.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#<%=DropDownList1.ClientID %>').css({ 'width': '10' });
    $('#<%=DropDownList1.ClientID %>'option).css({ 'width': '70' });

    alert("Testing."); 
  }); 
</script>
```

UPDATE: I was asked to provide some html from the code behind, there are over 3000 records available in the DDL, so here are the first few....

```
 <select name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder2$DropDownList1" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder2$DropDownList1\',\'\')', 0)" id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder2_DropDownList1">
<option selected="selected" value="434"> </option>
<option value="1160">-</option>
<option value="638"> 
</option>
<option value="702">    [%iScreen%]   = getnum(&quot;iScreen&quot;)
[%iButton%]   = getnum(&quot;iButton&quot;)
[%iProg%]     = getnum(&quot;iProg&quot;)
[%itest1%]    = getnum(&quot;itest1&quot;)
[%iSelectMY%] = getnum(&quot;iSelectMY&quot;)
[%iDSAPNO%]   = getnum(&quot;iDSAPNO&quot;)
[%iVehicle%]  = getnum(&quot;iVehicle&quot;)
[%iIESC%]     = getnum(&quot;iIESC&quot;)
[%iEngine%]   = getnum(&quot;iEngine&quot;)
[%iDSA%]      = getnum(&quot;iDSA&quot;)
[%iEXY%]      = getnum(&quot;iEXY&quot;)
[%iACCPNO%]   = getnum(&quot;iACCPNO&quot;)
[%sPart%]     = </option>
<option value="113">
</option>
<option value="342">
</option>
<option value="628">
    Isolation Solenoid

    Please Depress and Release Brake

    When You Press 'On' The Modulator is Drive For 15 Seconds.

    Check That No Braking Force Is Exerted.
</option>
<option value="2898">%</option>
<option value="3095">&amp;8BK</option>
<option value="3091">&amp;WZA</option>here
```

To long to list all, I realize there are block text in the options as well. This is the nature of the db backend which I have no control over.

Thank you,

Comment: could you inspect the html generated on this page and update your question with the html generated for the drop down list?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a space between the dropdownlist id and 'option' and option was outside of the string:

```
$('#<%=DropDownList1.ClientID %> option').css({ 'width': '70' });
```

Comment: Your syntax is correct thank you, but this method is not controlling the width of the DDL when the down arrow is clicked. The record length is still forcing the DDL width off the web page.

Answer (score 1):

You can't control the width of an `<option>` element, as they are contained within the drop-down UI. Only the `<select>` can have a width set.

Comment: roryf is right.  I don't know if this helps your situation (as I'm not sure what you need to adjust width for), but [check this link out](http://css-tricks.com/1994-select-cuts-off-options-in-ie-fix/).

Comment: some of my db records are almost 1000 characters. The width goes off the web page.

Comment: @JesseB - Thanks for the link, the issue for me is that I want to truncate the items, by I do not have a property for which to set the select width. The ASP control dropdownlilst box has width, but it automatically adjusts to the widest record in a databound connection, even if that record is not in the ddl display list.

Comment: So the problem is that any content within an `option` is inline, so line breaks are ignored. You're not going to solve this with a drop down, I'd recommend looking at an alternate UI for whatever you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I am not concerned with the line breaks, the record is the record. I just want to stop the dropdown list box from going full auto width. I'd like to set it at a width, say 280px, and have it stay there no matter what record it is displaying.

Comment: Changed to a Listbox to keep things moving along. This seems like a huge oversight, by the super powers.